# Detect when a SwiftUI sheet is swiped away

Tags: swift, swiftui

So I've got a sheet with a cancel button on the left and a done button on the right, like this:

```swift
.navigationBarItems(leading: Button(action: {
    // Code that dismisses sheet
}) {
    Text("Cancel")
}, trailing: Button(action: {
    // Code that adds something to something
}) {
    Text("Add").bold()
})
```

What I want to do is have a block of code execute when my SwiftUI 'sheet' is swiped away (down). This doesn't work with an `onDismiss` or `onDisappear` because they both execute on whatever button is pressed AND when it's swiped away.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: The `onDismiss` is a right place - just use app logic to handle correct flow. For instance enum with ok/cancel cases, or variable with block which is assigned in each button action, etc.

Comment: @Asperi What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: There is no *best* way, there are possible ways appropriate for application logic at some time. Which one to use is up to you ... anyway in next app version it might change.

Comment: @Asperi I ended up using this to fix my problem :) If you create a basic answer explaining it I'll mark it as accepted - Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`onDismiss` is enough, you need just to add another variable and check on it.

For example:
let's declare an `enum`

```
enum SheetAction {
    case cancel
    case nothing
}
```

Then in your Main View:

```
@State var sheetAction: SheetAction = SheetAction.nothing
```

Like that the default `action` which cause the dismiss will be `nothing` which means a swipe down, not a button.

And pass it to your `SheetView`

```
.sheet(isPresented: self.$sheetActive, onDismiss: {
    if sheetAction == .cancel {
        // dismissed using cancel button
        dismissTxt = "Cancel"
    }else if sheetAction == .nothing {
        // dismissed by swipe down
        dismissTxt = "Swipe down"
    }
}, content: {
    SheetView(isActive: self.$sheetActive, action: self.$sheetAction)
})
```

When the user click on `Cancel` button, change its value.
And don't miss to change the value to `nothing` each time the `SheetView` appears.

The final code:

```
enum SheetAction {
    case cancel
    case nothing
}

struct CustomView: View {
    
    @State var sheetActive = false
    @State var sheetAction: SheetAction = SheetAction.nothing
    
    @State var dismissTxt = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(dismissTxt).foregroundColor(.gray)
            Button(action: {
                self.sheetActive = true
            }, label: {
                Text("Button")
            })
        }.sheet(isPresented: self.$sheetActive, onDismiss: {
            if sheetAction == .cancel {
                // dismissed using cancel button
                dismissTxt = "Cancel"
            }else if sheetAction == .nothing {
                // dismissed by swipe down
                dismissTxt = "Swipe down"
            }
        }, content: {
            SheetView(isActive: self.$sheetActive, action: self.$sheetAction)
        })
    }
}

struct SheetView: View {
    @Binding var isActive: Bool
    @Binding var action: SheetAction
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("Sheet content")
            }
            .navigationBarItems(leading: Button(action: {
                // Code that dismisses sheet
                self.action = .cancel
                self.isActive = false
            }) {
                Text("Cancel")
            }, trailing: Button(action: {
                // Code that adds something to something
            }) {
                Text("Add").bold()
            })
        }.onAppear {
            action = .nothing
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! This is a really great answer! Thanks so much :)